# How to remove "<a id="12" />" from string

Tags: php, regex, xhtml

I have an xhtml string, and it contains:

```
<a id="8" />
```

The number is random each time. It does not have an href attribute, so maybe removing all `<a>` without href is an option? I want to remove those parts with PHP, what is my best approach?

I would like to use tidy, but I don't think it has an option to remove those tags.

If that is not possible, I believe `preg_replace()` with regex is my second best approach. However, I do not know the regex string to remove those parts.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: If the id is set with a function that just outputs a random number, you can just get that random number in a variable, then use it in the link but keep the variable and use it to identify which <a> tag to remove.

Comment: Are you using any XML parsing library/functions?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it, by finding out why this piece of code was added to the XHTML string in the first place. I removed it, thereby solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:** `<a\s+id="[^"]*"[^\/]\/>`

```
$re = "/<a\\s+id=\"[^\"]*\"[^\\/]\\/>/mi"; 
$str = "<a id=\"8\" />\njdf\nsadfa\n<a id=\"df\" />\n<a name=\"df\" />"; 
$subst = ""; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

And only remove `<a id="8" />`  then use `<a\s+id="8"[^\/]\/>`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rB1yZ8/4)**

Comment: This also removes said string from inside comments and CDATA blocks, does it not?